# php function preg_replace with regex not working, a syntax question

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre

im trying to replace a remove unnessary new lines with preg-replace but my regex is incorrect. Anyone any ideas whats wrong with my regex? (i have Apache/2.0.54 & PHP/5.2.9

## NOW HAVE:

```
{
blaa {
blow;
blue};
bell;}
}ball
```

## WOULD LIKE:

```
{blaa {blow;blue};bell;}}ball
```

## These regex dont work, they remove too much or toolitle??

```
$buffer = preg_replace('#/\}\n|\r|\s/#s', '}', $buffer);
$buffer = preg_replace('#/\{\n|\r|\s/#s', '{', $buffer);
$buffer = preg_replace('#/\;\n|\r|\s/#s', ';', $buffer);
```

/g (global) gives blanc content and without the # it doestnt do anything. strange?!
Anybody any clue why these dont work?

Comment: `\s` does already contain `\r` and `\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove any whitespace after `{`, `}`, and `;`, do this:

```
preg_replace('/([{};])\s+/', '$1', $buffer)
```

Here `/` are the [delimiters](http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters); `([{};])` describes one character of `{`, `}`, and `;` while the match is captured; and `\s+` describes any following whitespace characters (already including `\r` and `\n`).

Comment: Thanks Gumbo for the explanation as well!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$buffer = preg_replace('#([{};])(?:\n|\r|\s)#s', '$1', $buffer);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$buffer = preg_replace('/\}\\n|\\r|\\s/', '', $buffer);
```

Comment: The OP was already using single-quoted strings, so the backslashes were not the problem. (Doubling them actually had no effect; the PHP parser just removes the extras before the *regex* parser ever sees them.)